# Google Calendar API：Calendar usage limits exceeded

Tags: python, calendar, limit, quota

My work is migration calendar data, we're using google calendar API.
The number of Target Data is 280,000.

The method to execute is as follows.
・Calender API V3 Event-insert
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert
・batch request
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/batch
・exponential backoff

It has been running many times for this test, and it was able to run without problems before.
However, it currently has an error indication "Calendar usage limits exceeded", a state where it can not be executed even once and lasted for about a week.

I understand that the cause is as follows.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en

QPD(quota per date) had been changed to 2,000,000 by the support .
Therefore, I think that the problem by quota can be solved.
However, Currently, I am currently in a state where I can not execute the API even once I run the program.
I want to eliminate this situation.
I think that it is probably necessary to cancel restrictions on google side.
Can I borrow your wisdom?

Comment: question in Japanese should be posted at https://ja.stackoverflow.com/